# Angular 2 Unit test Error: Cannot resolve all parameters DecoratorFactory:(?)

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

I want to test a simple component that have some Dependencies. So among others I have to provide some providers
    describe('AccountLookupComponent', () => {
        let component: AccountLookupComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture`enter code here`;

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                TestComponentWrapper,
                AccountLookupComponent
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            imports: [HttpModule],
            providers: [AccountLookupService, AuthHttp, AuthenticationService, AdalService, AdfsSecretService, CookieService, NgModule,
                { provide: 'IAccountLookupClient', useClass: AccountLookupClient },
                { provide: 'IApiClient', useClass: ApiClient },
                { provide: 'ITimeoutService', useClass: TimeoutService },

            ]

        })
            .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponentWrapper);
        component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});

@Component({
    selector: 'test-component-wrapper',
    template: `<account-lookup filterCurrentAccount="true"
                                [useAccountIdSearch]="true"
                                [useCompactResults]="true"
                                (accountSelected)="null"
                                placeholder="Find account">
                </account-lookup>`,

})
class TestComponentWrapper {


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `NgModule` from `providers` array. It is decorator. You should not use it as token.

```
export function makeDecorator(
    name: string, props?: (...args: any[]) => any, parentClass?: any,
    chainFn?: (fn: Function) => void): (...args: any[]) => (cls: any) => any {
  const metaCtor = makeMetadataCtor(props);

  function DecoratorFactory(objOrType: any): (cls: any) => any { // => here is your provider
```

Comment: when i remove NgModule  it's give me this error   No provider for NgbModal!

Comment: Import NgbModule.forRoot() or NgbModalModule.forRoot() instead

Answer (score 0):

There are Two way to test component with providers

**1. Inject the real services.**

**2. Use test doubles (stubs, fakes, spies, or mocks).**

First Method A component doesn't have to be injected with real services but you can do something like that example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
  providers:    [ ExampleService ]]
});
```

The Other Method is using stubs example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
   // Provide a test-double instead
   providers:    [ {provide: ExampleService, useValue: exampleServiceStub }]
});

// UserService from the root injector
exampleService = TestBed.get(ExampleService);
```

Comment: You're trying to import decorator in Providers array. why you add NgModule to providers??  It should contain only Services.

Comment: i now it;s decorator but it's give me this error :::inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for NgbModal!